# Use case of nesting an enum into a struct

Tags: c#, enum

At our office there is this piece of code (the original author isn't employed anymore, so I can't ask him).

Does anybody have an idea, what he did there? Is there any advantage of using this struct `OrderDirection` instead directly the enum `Direction`?

(for me, this is interesting and I just wanted to know why.)

```
public struct OrderDirection 
{
    private enum Direction
    {
        Ascending = 0,
        Descending = 1
    }
    
    private OrderDirection(Direction direction)
    {
        _direction = direction;
    }
    
    private readonly Direction _direction;
    
    public override string ToString()
    {
        switch(_direction)
        {
            case Direction.Ascending: return "asc";
            case Direction.Descending: return "desc";
            default: throw new NotImplementedException(nameof(_direction));
        }
    }
    
    public static OrderDirection Ascending = new OrderDirection(Direction.Ascending);
    public static OrderDirection Descending = new OrderDirection(Direction.Descending);
}
```

Comment: First, it looks like a decently object-oriented (specifically, polymorphism) approach to letting the `ToString()` method do the real work of representing what the value is. You'd certainly need to find out where it's being used to get that answer, but that's my guess looking at it. Second, mark those `public static` values as `readonly` - don't need some random code changing what is assigned to `Ascending` or `Descending`.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer so (besides the missing `readonly`) this actually is good code? haha, sorry never seen someone before doing this. He uses it to build sql-queries with stringbuilder and things..

Comment: I see no need for the `enum` when a simple `bool` would suffice.  The original programmer kept all other details hidden that all you should care about is using the static instances, and both of them can be easily be created without the enum.

Comment: @MatthiasBurger It models the business domain very well, even if it is a little over the top for something this small. I'm not really a fan of the `NotImplementedException`. That shouldn't be necessary (nor the `default` label) because all enum values are covered in the switch labels. If you added a different enum value called "Unknown" with the zero value, I could see it. But as-is, no.

Comment: @MatthiasBurger on the other hand, `ToString()` should never throw exceptions.

Comment: In general I'd put that check in the constructor, not `ToString()` -- though in this case it shouldn't be needed, not because the two cases are covered by the `switch`, but because the constructor is inaccessible to anyone but this struct where we can prove that it'll only ever be called with those two enum values. Otherwise a caller could create a `new OrderDirection((Direction)123)`. In any case, you can change the `default` block to an `Debug.Assert(true)`: it should be _impossible_ for that branch to be reached in the struct as provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion nothing indicate the use of `enum`.

According to my understanding your object provides the following functionalities from consumer perspective:

- Provide two factory methods one for **Ascending** and another for **Descending**
- Provide custom string representation (abbreviation) for these

From the public interface point of view the following implementation is equivalent with yours

```
public struct OrderDirection 
{
    private readonly string _direction;
    private OrderDirection(string direction)
    {
        _direction = direction;
    }
      
    public override string ToString() => _direction;
    
    public static OrderDirection Ascending = new OrderDirection("asc");
    public static OrderDirection Descending = new OrderDirection("desc");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as OOP as is, I think this would avoid unneeded castings, and it gives you more managed approach to handle `enum` than using `enum` directly.

If `enum` was used directly, it would be possible to cast it to different type than a string, and it will make your hands tight when it comes to handle exceptions. so using `struct` with an internal `enum` would force typing it to only accept and output specified types, which avoid unnecessary exceptions and give you more OOP options to work with.

This is also a security approach where it adds restrictions on the input-output. In this case, avoiding `SQL Injections`.

Obviously it can be done in different approaches, however, this implementation would avoid some of the human-errors (like misspelling), and overriding. It would also add more readability and maintainability to the code and avoiding redundancy with less code possible.